# Notation of a function

Tags: functions

For a reciprocal function:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ the domain is given by
$\operatorname{Domain}(f)=\Bbb R-\{0\}$ and the range by $\operatorname{Range}(f)=\Bbb R-\{0\}$.
But while writing the function we write

> "$f\colon \Bbb R-\{0\}\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x \in\Bbb R-\{0\}$"

Why dont we write $f\colon \Bbb R-\{0\}\to \Bbb R-\{0\}$, as the range is $\Bbb R-\{0\}$?

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: @KennyLau Given in my textbook

Comment: You can write both ways. However if the range is R then it is not a surjective function.

Comment: Usually in the notation $f:A\rightarrow B$, $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $B$ the codomain. Otherwise it would make little sense to talk about surjective functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range of the function does not need to be all of the numbers it **does** reach, it can be more. That's why we have a special name for functions which **do** cover the entire domain, and that name is "surjective".

In your case, the range of $f$ is $\mathbb R$, and the function is **not** surjective. You can also define the range to be $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, in which case you actually defined a *different* function, this time it is surjective.

Comment: You raise an interesting point: when do we consider two functions as equal? You ask for equality of the codomains as well, arguing that otherwise different properties, here surjectivity, might result. My gut feeling is that just blowing up the codomain (without new image values there) should not matter and [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/471346/86776) seems to be along that point of view.

Comment: @mvw In category theory you would say that two functions are equal if they have the same domain and codomain and they agree on all values because the place you are comparing them is within Hom sets. This is a very natural setting.

Comment: @mvw I think "blowing up" a codomain should matter, otherwise surjectivity is ill defined.

Comment: @5xum I understand your position and its virtue. Right now I think different concepts of equality exist, as drhab states.

Answer (score 0):

You could write $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{C}$ as well. It could be any set that includes all image values.

I would prefer $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ as well, as you have to start your analysis at $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is the main theater of war here.

Note: This implies a view which considers both functions, despite the different codomains, as equal (as they have the same domain and same graph).

Answer (score 0):

Some theory about functions.

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function and its range $R:=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}\subseteq Y$ then for any set $S$ with $R\subseteq S\subseteq Y$ we also have a function $g:X\to S$ that is prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$.

The graph of function $f$ is the set $G_f:=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times Y\mid y=f(x)\}$.

The graphs of $f$ and $g$ coincide, so if functions are *identified* with their graphs then there is no essential difference between $f$ and $g$.

There are fields in mathematics where this is common (e.g. sets).

Also there are fields where it is common to identify function $f$ with triple $\langle X,G_f,Y\rangle$ (e.g. categories) and in that perspective $f=\langle X,G_f,Y\rangle$ and $g=\langle X,G_g,S\rangle$ are distinct functions if $S\neq Y$.